# Case Creation for Person Accounts via API

Tags: api, person-accounts

I wish to create Cases for org with Person Account enabled via SOAP API.

Using the SOAP UI tool to create case, the Contact Id field cannot have the Account Id field (as both are same for Person Accounts)

As per the official document:

http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/14/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_B2C_implementation_guide.pdf

"On cases, person accounts can be entered in the Account Name field, the Contact Name field, or both"

Please suggest if case can be created for Person Accounts via API.

Thanks!